# How to play the video from src field returned by fql query facebook in iphone

Tags: iphone, facebook

I want to play the video which is returend in src field by querying facebook video object in iphone

```
"src": "http://video.l3.fbcdn.net/cfs-l3-ash4/232135/599/109331539158851_26788.mp4?oh=2693efb2a308c968d5b6d584ab5f6350&oe=4E255800&l3s=20110717030008&l3e=20110719031008&lh=08f7a6ffbdf58953de616", 

"src_hq": "http://video.l3.fbcdn.net/cfs-l3-ash4/232135/599/109331539158851_26788.mp4?oh=2693efb2a308c968d5b6d584ab5f6350&oe=4E255800&l3s=20110717030008&l3e=20110719031008&lh=08f7a6ffbdf58953de616"
```

Can you point out some sample code (iphone sdk example ) or existing application through which i can play this video in my iphone?

Answer (score 0):

Try this as an example:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *mediaPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:<#movieURL#>];
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[viewController.view addSubview:mediaPlayer.view];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:viewController];
[mediaPlayer play];
```

Let me know if this works for you. Thanks!